# SQL: Query to retrieve student age at time of re admission

Tags: sql

I need to find the age of student when he was readmitted to a class.
Now to do this I have one table student_history hence first needed to retrieve the "admin_date" admission date from student history when student status equals to 'RE-ADMIN're admitted. And then to check if  admin_date is greater than admin_date of last Readmission 'RE-ADMIN' or Completed 'COMP' in records.
Now the query is not working as it should be and running into different errors.

```
SELECT
    s.admin_date
FROM
    student_history s
WHERE
    student_st = 'RE-ADMIN'
    AND
    s.admin_date > (
        SELECT
            s.admin_date
        FROM
            s
        WHERE
            student_st IN('RE-ADMIN','COMP')
    )
```

couple of similar links researched.

[Age Calculation Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465010/age-calculation-query)
[comparison query taking ages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040908/comparison-query-taking-ages)

Comment: What error message is produced? It looks like the subquery in your where clause will produce more than one record, which will cause a problem.

Comment: I seriously doubt you can figure out how old somebody is based solely on when you admitted them... you need a birthdate.  Could we get some starting data and sample results?

Answer (score 0):

Change your WHERE subquery to this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(s.admin_date)
FROM
    student_history
WHERE
    student_id = @studentId
    AND
    student_st IN ( 'RE-ADMIN', 'COMP' )
```

You'll also need to add your `student_id = @studentId` predicate to the outerquery.

Answer (score 0):

Dai is right you have to add student id for omitting the error. But by this you will get last re-admission date. how will you calculate his age with admission date. you need dob field for this.